# Setting static variable in compiled ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have compiled ASP.NET dynamic page with editable aspx pages. 
I would like to some links to be generated upon changing some static variable 
What i did is edit:

web.config as follows:

```
<appSettings>
       <add key="currentEnvironment" value="dev-"/>
</appSettings>
```

and then
edited aspx page as follows

```
 <a href="http://<asp:Literal runat ="server" Text='<%# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["currentEnvironment"] %>'></asp:Literal>www.mysite.com/web/index.html">Home</a>
```

But there is nothing appened when i try and run the .aspx page. Please help

Comment: ICBW, but don't all `asp:` controls need an `ID`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, they don't necessarily need an ID. Though I'm not sure why one would do that. But it will work.

Comment: Hi, the problem was that site was already compiled and i want to just add one static variable, without recompiling code,as i am no author of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a server tag inside another tag's markup like that, but you can just use the value directly. If you remove it and change the `#` to a `=`, it will work.

```
<a href="http://<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["currentEnvironment"] %>www.mysite.com/web/index.html">Home</a>
```

Although if you can access the code behind, that would be a much cleaner way to do it, as in:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="_index" runat="server">Home</asp:HyperLink>
```

and then set value from code behind

```
_index.NavigateUrl = String.Format("http://{0}www.mysite.com/web/index.html", ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["currentEnvironment"]);
```